# eclipse doesn't recognise correction of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse with Android projects.    Sometimes when I recompile with clean Eclipse will mark errors in red. and sometimes but not always after I have corrected therrors and recompile the error messages are still there.   If I close and reopen the project and reopen all is well.   Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this can happen with non-java related things. Like converting .class files to dalvik format, or some changes in resources can produce errors that are not recovered when you fix them.

In this cases you can just delete the error message from "Problems" tab and re-build the project from scratch (i.e. Clean, then Build). This usually solves such issues.

But from my experience such "unrecoverable" errors are relatively rare.